# How to boost MP4 video volume in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, mp4parser

How to programmatically boost the MP4 video volume just like MX player can increase the volume up to 200%

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

call

> **setVolumeControlStream()**

on your **Activity**, probably supplying a value of

> **AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC**

as the stream to adjust.

If you wish to provide your own on-screen volume control, see the **[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)** class.

Comment: I am trying to do is to boost volume not increase it.